# How to remove scroll bar in PublisherAdView DFP?

Tags: android, scrollbar, google-dfp

I use *doubleclick* in banner ads, but the ads are being display also with scroll bar.

How can I remove that?

*Follows a screenshot: [screenshot of PublisherAdView with scrollbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emPw7.png)*

Comment: Did you ever found a solution for this?

Comment: No At please also foound please tell me.. thannx

Comment: Having the same problem. Any solution ?

Comment: could you provide a test page by any chance ?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone is still looking for a solution:

I found that one of the child views for PublisherAdView is actually a WebView, however, there's no easy way to disable the scrollbars since those views are not accessible via public API. To get around it, I wrote a function to traverse the child views inside PublisherAdView and disable any Webview scrollbars manually.

Here is a sample code that works for me:

```kotlin
fun ViewGroup.hideWebViewScrollbars() {
    for (i in 0 until childCount) {
        val child = getChildAt(i)
        (child as? WebView)?.let {
            it.isVerticalScrollBarEnabled = false
            it.isHorizontalScrollBarEnabled = false
        }
        if (child is ViewGroup) {
            child.hideWebViewScrollbars()
        }
    }
}
```